# Increase Rise and Fall Time of this Schematic

Tags: mosfet, pwm, level-shifting

The following cirucit converts a 3.3V PWM signal into a +-12V PWM signal and works as expected. I want to increase the rise and fall time of the ouput signal to approx 2us. How can this be done?

[image]
[image]

**Update:**

How about an output filter?

BTW - The ouput wire is approx. 7-8 meters long.

Comment: increase the resistor r21 (1k)

Comment: Increase C6 in value.

Comment: I'd use BJTs: cheaper and work fine and I'd have no problem getting well below a microsecond on the edges with them. But have you considered a capacitor (appropriately sized) between the gates of M3 and M7. This way, pulling up on M3's gate pushes up hard on M7's gate turning it off more sharply. The reverse is also true. Just a thought. But again, everything matters and surrounding resistors may need changes, too.

Comment: FYI: With BJTs in simulation, I get rise and fall times (using a 10k load) not worse than 350 ns, even with junk box parts. Using fast BJTs like the BFT93 and BFR93 or BFR91A (assuming you use good wiring techniques, the results should be close) I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rVoe.png) for a 24 V swing using 5 V drive. Bipolar rails, not yet tested, should be similar. I'm sure mosfets can get you there, too. I just don't use them as much for this kind of thing.

Comment: @jonk the OP says he wants to "increase" the rise and fall time. I assume that means make it more sluggish.

Comment: @Andyaka Hmm. Thanks. My mistake. I guess the OP will have no problems at all, then. Big mosfets with lots of gate charge, big resistor values, weak drive currents, and large capacitance loading should get there. Oh, and definitely use cheap solderless breadboards and long jumper wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gate-drain capacitors on M3 and M7.  You can also add a series gate-drain resistance, but you already have effectively 500 ohms on each.  1000pF should get you in the range of 2us, but you could probably dial it in more experimentally.  If you want to use a smaller cap, you could add series gate resistors.  This is one of the better controlled methods, because the feedback is right on the output stage where you're trying to create the effect.

Comment: Adding these gate-drain caps somehow really works, but it gives me a different rise time for the -12V to 0V and the 0V to +6V part. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That's probably because D2 makes the load R22||R23 visible only when the output is over 0.7V.  It's creating a voltage divider between itself and the 1K, but only on the positive side.  The drain voltage is probably changing at a constant rate.  Try connecting the caps to the output instead of to the drains and see if that helps.

Comment: seems to work! Thank you @Cristobol

Answer (score 0):

- Increase the value of C6 as @Andyaka suggested.
- You can also change the pulse signal properties to increase the rise time and fall time. Also, making rise time and fall time too high will increase the power dissipation.

[image]

Comment: To go along wit this, some microcontrollers allow you to control their drive strength or slew.

Comment: Changing the rise and fall time of the input signal is not really affecting the output.